# spring data jpa, share entities over projects, unmapped entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a couple of services who use the same form of table to store translations, so I moved the translation entity into a shared project and try to have a unidirectional @OneToMany mapping on that entity. However I keep getting following exception 
`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.examples.blog.Post.translations[com.examples.shared.domain.Translation]`

my Post class looks like this

```
package com.examples.blog.domain;

import com.examples.shared.domain.Translation;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSTS")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    private String author;

    @Embedded
    private Source source;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
    List<Translation> translations;

}
```

and my shared Translation class looks like this:

```
package com.examples.shared.domain;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSLATIONS")
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Translation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "language")
    private String language;

    @Column(name="translation")
    private String translation;

    @Column(name="entity_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private String entityId;

}
```

Anyone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I also have added the packages to my basePackages 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.examples"})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like hibernate is not aware of `com.examples.shared.domain.Translation` entity.
You should provide hibernate a list of classes or packages where it should look for `@Entities` classes.

If you use `Spring Boot` use `@EntityScan(basePackages="com.examples.shared.domain")`.

If you use `Spring` + `Hibernate` integration, use         `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.examples.shared.domain")`

If you use plain hibernate, add a corresponding entry to **persistence.xml** or **hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    ....
    <mapping class="com.examples.shared.domain.Translation"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Or for java config see docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-bootstrap-native-registry-MetadataSources-example

Answer (score 2):

Below statement is causing you issue:

```
  @Column(name="entity_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private String entityId;
```

Instead of String `entityId`, you should mention relationship with a valid entity class. Here `entityId` is of type `String` which is obviously not a declared entity.

Comment: well as stated above the Translation Entity will be shared over many different services, so this time it's Post, next time it's MenuEntry, ... so how would I be able to do it like that?

Comment: In that case the simplest way would be to remove @ManytoOne annotation from entityid field

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping 2nd class in onetomany in one class but mapping manytoone to a string instead of class.

Change

```
@ManyToOne
private String entityId;
```

to

```
@ManyToOne
private Currency entityId;
```

See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)